# Task scheduler history on who enabled a task

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

We have several deactivated scheduled tasks and someone activated one. Is there a way to see who did that?

There is no such information on the task's history.

It is on windows server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, more or less...

In the Event Viewer -> **Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TaskScheduler -> Operational**, look for Event ID `140` : `Task registration updated`, it shows you the username that "updated" the scheduled task, so, this is not a proof that the user *enabled* the task, but at least this will tell you that someone changed something in this scheduled task.